# Why can't I use integration by parts immediately here without using trigo identities?

Tags: calculus, integration

Basically the question is to integrate this:

$$ \int \cos x \cdot \cos 9x \space dx $$

I want to know if it is okay to do integration by parts immediately without simplifying it with trigonometric identities? If not, could you explain why?

The modal answer is:

$
\frac{1}{20}sin10x + \frac{1}{16}sin8x+C
$

But if I want to use by parts for example, I chose $u$ and $dv$ to be:
$$u=\cos x$$
$$dv=\cos 9x$$

**update1** here is my attempted solution as requested but could not deduce the modal answer:
[image]

**update2:** there are solutions provided but it is not the same as the modal answer. Is it technically the same? Just that we have to play around with the identities to match the modal answer?

Comment: @insipidintegrator I get a different answer and I'm not sure if its my mistake along the integration process. Sorry I am new to integration thus it could be a simple question

Comment: You're free to do integration by parts, but whether it leads you to a nice solution is up to you. Either doing that or using trig identities should lead you to the right answer regardless.

Comment: @Accelerator is it possible to provide a working solution by parts? I tried it but could not deduce the same answer as using the tirgo identities.

Comment: It's possible that your answer is correct, but you still need to use trigonometric identities if you want to check that its difference with the answer key is a constant.

Comment: @insipidintegrator i provided my workings and the modal answers above!

Comment: You have product-to-sum wrong: $\sin x\sin y=\frac12(\cos (x-y)-\cos(x+y))$.

Comment: The mistake is saying that $\frac{1}{9}\sin\left(9x\right)\sin\left(x\right) = \frac{1}{18}\left(\sin\left(9x+x\right)+\sin\left(9x-x\right)\right)$, which isn't true. Also, you don't have to be sorry for asking what's considered a simple question to most of us. This site welcomes anyone with any math skill as long as they show their effort. (P.S. images are generally discouraged on this site unless the picture is impossible to recreate on Mathjax)

Comment: Thank you guys! I appreciate your time

Answer (score 4):

I mean, you could, but where would that lead you?

$$u = \cos x, \quad du = -\sin x \, dx, \\ dv = \cos 9x \, dx, \quad v = \frac{1}{9}\sin 9x$$ yields
$$\int \cos x \cos 9x \, dx = \frac{1}{9} \cos x \sin 9 x + \frac{1}{9} \int \sin 9x \sin x \, dx. \tag{1}$$

The integral on the right hand side does not appear to be any easier to evaluate than the one we started with.

But maybe not all is lost:  note that $$\cos x \cos 9x - \sin x \sin 9x = \cos(9x + x) = \cos 10x \tag{2}$$ from the cosine angle addition identity $$\cos (\alpha + \beta) = \cos \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \alpha \sin \beta$$ with the choice $\alpha = 9x$, $\beta = x$.  Therefore, $$\int \cos 10x \, dx = \int \cos x \cos 9x - \sin x \sin 9x \, dx. \tag{3}$$  If we let $$I_1 = \int \cos x \cos 9x \, dx, \quad I_2 = \int \sin x \sin 9x \, dx,$$ then Equation $(1)$ becomes $$9I_1 = \cos x \sin 9x + I_2, \tag{4}$$ and Equation $(3)$ becomes $$I_1 - I_2 = \int \cos 10x \, dx = \frac{1}{10} \sin 10x + C.$$  Therefore, $$I_2 = I_1 - \frac{1}{10} \sin 10x + C \tag{5}$$
and substituting this into Equation $(4)$ gives
$$9I_1 = \cos x \sin 9x + I_1 - \frac{1}{10} \sin 10 x + C.$$  Now solve for $I_1$:
$$I_1 = \frac{1}{8} \left(\cos x \sin 9x - \frac{1}{10} \sin 10x\right) + C.$$

Of course, the whole thing could have been done more easily if we had applied a different trigonometric identity in the first place:

$$\cos \alpha \cos \beta = \frac{\cos(\alpha + \beta) + \cos(\alpha - \beta)}{2}. \tag{6}$$

This identity follows directly from the cosine angle addition identity, and for the same choice of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we get

$$\cos x \cos 9x = \frac{1}{2}(\cos 10x + \cos 8x),$$ the integral of which is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Integrate the first term and differentiate the second twice to get a nontrivial relation for the integral:
$$I=\int\cos x\cos9x\,dx=\sin x\cos9x-(-9)\int\sin x\sin9x\,dx$$
$$=\sin x\cos9x+9\left(-\cos x\sin9x-(-9)\int\cos x\cos9x\,dx\right)$$
$$I=\sin x\cos9x-9\cos x\sin9x+81I$$
$$I=\frac1{80}(-\sin x\cos9x+9\cos x\sin9x)+K$$
So yes, it does work, but you have to put in a proportionate amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the book has probably done.

Consider $I_1 = \int (\cos x)(\cos 9x) \ dx, I_2 = \int (\sin x)(\sin 9x) \ dx$. $I_1 + I_2 = \int \cos(x - 9x) = \frac{1}{8} \sin(8x) + C_1$ and $I_1 - I_2 = \int \cos(x + 9x) = \frac{1}{10} \sin(10x) + C_2$.

Summing these up, $2I_1 = \frac{1}{8} \sin(8x) + \frac{1}{10} \sin(10x) + C$ which gives the stated answer.